# Dump csv with non latin characters into a mysql table

Tags: csv, utf-8, mysql, thai

I want to create a sql table from a csv. 
Inside this csv I have a field 'first name' with some Thai characters, so I set the type as utf8 in my sql table. To dump the csv I'm using this command line:

```
mysql -hlocalhost -uroot -p***** --default-character-set=utf8 TH -e "
load data local infile
'/home/tom/th_customer.csv'
into table customer
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
ignore 1 lines
"
```

But instead of getting the Thai characters, I just have ????
any suggestion please?

Comment: *Where* does `????` appear?

Comment: in the mysql database @Biffen

Comment: And how are you looking ‘in’ the database? It *could* be that the data is *stored* correctly, but whatever you use to view it messes up the encoding.

Comment: just phpmyadmin @Biffen

Answer (score 0):

Try issuing these commands before the LOAD command:

```
set session collation_database=utf8_general_ci;
set session character_set_database=utf8;
```